# Cómo añadir un campo en el header de un HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, spring

Tengo un interceptor de solicitudes http de esta forma:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
//
response.setHeader("probando", "test");
response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_RANGES, "test");
return true;
}
```

en el cual quiero agregar campos a la respuesta pero no lo añade de ninguna forma, alguien sabe el por qué o si hay otra forma de agregarlos?

Comment: Estás seguro que tu interceptor se ejecuta? Los has anotado con @Component, y lo has agregado al registro de interceptors?

Comment: Hola @Alex, si, se ejecuta, tengo más código que evité poner porque no vienen al problema

Comment: Lo he agregado como service además

Answer (score 0):

Mira, escribí este pequeño ejemplo que funciona perfectamente:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new Interceptor());
    }

    @Controller("/")
    public class HeaderCheck {

        @GetMapping
        @ResponseBody
        public String verifyHeader(HttpServletResponse response) {
            return String.format("El header es %s", response.getHeader("probando"));
        }
    }

    public class Interceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
            response.setHeader("probando", "test");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Si haces una petición a http://localhost:8080, obtienes

`El header es test`